# Print unique lines that also match pattern

Tags: bash, awk

Given this `foo.txt`

```
/bin/bar:
        KERNELBASE => /sbin/KERNELBASE (0x77670000)
        intl-8 => /usr/bin/intl-8 (0x6f970000)
        iconv-2 => /usr/bin/iconv-2 (0x6f980000)
        pcre-0 => /usr/bin/pcre-0 (0x6f780000)
        gcc_s-1 => /usr/bin/gcc_s-1 (0x6fdd0000)
/bin/baz:
        KERNELBASE => /sbin/KERNELBASE (0x77670000)
        intl-8 => /usr/bin/intl-8 (0x6f970000)
        iconv-2 => /usr/bin/iconv-2 (0x6f980000)
```

I would like this output

```
/usr/bin/intl-8
/usr/bin/iconv-2
/usr/bin/pcre-0
/usr/bin/gcc_s-1
```

That is to say, I would like to take unique lines containing `/usr`, then print the correct field. Currently I am using a pipe

```sh
grep /usr foo.txt | sort -u | cut -d' ' -f3
```

However could this be done with a oneline `awk` command? I
[came across](http://pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt)
this example

```sh
awk '!a[$0]++'
```

but I cannot see how to use this with only `/usr` lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 awk '/\usr/ && ! a[$0]++{print $3}' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern matching in awk is one of its great advantages. Your example uses some shortcuts for simple cases, but an equivalent command to `awk '!a[$0]++'` is `awk '($0 in a) {a[$0]; print}'`, which leads quite easily to adding an additional pattern. Also printing only the third field yields:

```
awk '/\/usr/ && !($0 in a) {a[$0]; print $3}'
```